# TextBox To Double Then Show as String AlertView

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am having trouble getting a double to show up in my alert view.  The string keeps showing up as 0 in the AlertView.  Thanks in advance!

```
    double binRadius = [txtRadiusInches.text doubleValue] / 12 + [txtRadiusFeet.text doubleValue];
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", binRadius];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Estimatated Amount"
                                                message:myString
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Clear All", nil];

[alert show];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` (and `%i`) is the format specifier for integers (decimals). For floating point numbers you should use `%f`.